# Select all rows and multiple ranges of columns in pandas 0.25.1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that contains 70 columns and I want to extract all rows, the first 4 columns and the last 54 columns. I've tried the following:

```
df_3 = df_3.iloc[:, [0:3, 16:70]]
```

but it keeps saying it's the wrong syntax...
Then  I tried using np.r_ (although I'm not sure if I understand what it really does, I prefer a solution with iloc)

```
df_3 = df_3.iloc[:, np.r_[0:3, 16:69]]
```

but this returns the first 4 column twice, and the columns in the middle (4:15) which are the ones I want to get rid of...
Then I tried this code:

```
df_3 = df_3.iloc[:, [0:3, -54:]]
```

but it returns same output as above, with np.r_

and my latest try
`df_3 = df_3.iloc[:, [+4:, -54:]]`
returns a syntax error...

My python version is 3.7.4 and pandas version is 0.25.1

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thank you all  in advance

Comment: ``df_3.iloc[:, np.r_[0:4, 16:70]]`` does not work? ``np.r_`` is just a convenient way to generate arrays. ``np.r_[0:4, 16:70]`` will generate a 1D array of [0,1,2,3,] as well as [16,17,18,...69]. iloc can then use that information to get your columns

Comment: @sammywemmy. thats's what I thought... but  it doesn't work; what i get is the first 4 columns duplicated and  those columns in the middle, which i want to remove :( Also, Im not sure how relevant this may be but, I'm using Spyder 3 to run my code. Could it be something to do with this?

Comment: nahhh. it should not duplicate. i dont think it has anything to do with spyder 3. what if you tried : ``pd.concat([df_3.iloc[:, :4], df_3.iloc[:, 16:70]], axis=1)`` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using df.columns & df.loc

Take the first 4 columns and last 54 columns, turn them to lists and add them up. Then access those columns at the data frame using .loc

```
df_3 = df_3.loc[:, df_3.columns[0:4].to_list() + df_3.columns[-54:].to_list()]
```